# Play on Linux LOL Error

Tags: playonlinux

I am trying to play LOL on ubuntu through wine and playonlinux. It works great, but I'm not able to buy anything from the store. It asks for authentication, I type in my username and password, but it keeps saying "unable to purchase item: unknown error". How did y'all solve this issue?

Comment: The community is more willing to put in effort to help if you demonstrate effort yourself. In this case, you don't show any research effort. I found this quickly via Google: [UNKNOWN ERROR](http://boards.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/c/help-support/gZBxrpjQ-unknown-error). I would normally downvote a low-effort question, but you're a new user so I understand.

Answer (score 2):

I looked up LOL (I assume you mean League of Legends) on the PlayOnLinux install menu and in the [Known Issues](https://www.playonlinux.com/de/app-1135-League_Of_Legends.html) list it states the following:

> Known issues:
>
> - The updater sometimes stalls. If it doesn't move for minutes, close it then restart the game.
> - **Store does not work** (Blank Screen)

This appears to be a problem with PlayOnLinux. You will either have to contact the PlayOnLinux team, or find a way to get around the problem yourself.